# xreader closes after pdflatex compilation

Tags: linux-mint, pdf, evince

I just installed Linux Mint 18 and began using the default pdf reader: `xreader`. However, sometimes when I leave a pdf open and compile it using pdflatex the program closes with this message:

> (xreader:25493): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
>
> (xreader:25493): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'EvWebView'

This never happened with evince and I think it shouldn't happen. I could switch back to `evince` (assuming they're not the same program renamed) but I liked to X-apps initiative and would like to keep `xreader`.

What might be causing this and how could I fix it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/25). And this other one is [possibly related](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/11).

And it seems to have been fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/pull/28). Try compiling and then installing `xreader` from its latest commit in the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. As a workaround, when invoking pdflatex, I use something like

```
pdflatex whateverfile.tex; xdg-open whateverfile.pdf
```

This will immediately reopen the PDF. Although this is not a full solution, I find that it still works ok for me.